# Punching someone so hard that they become a duck

Tags: product-identification, exalted

I was reading 1d4chan's [description of the exalted](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Exalted).  In it while describing Sidereal Exalted, it mentions punching someone so hard that they turn into a duck (before saying it makes more sense in context). I know White Wolf publishing has stories or story-like descriptions in almost all of their books. What I want to ask is: which book is the context from?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is from the [Scroll of the Monk](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/23404/Scroll-of-the-Monk?it=1).

The Charm they are referring to is the Charm *Pattern Spider Touch* (page 124) which opens with...

> Once, changes to the Loom of Fate could change anything in Creation. The pattern spiders, which tend the Loom, no longer permit swift and drastic changes, but the potential remains. With a successful unarmed attack, a character can use this Charm to fundamentally change his target, reweaving the structure of the target's existence. Doing so causes one of the following effects.

It then goes on to list a range of horrifically powerful effects that are generally considered to be utterly gamebreaking.

The effect that 1d4chan is referring to is this...

> Transforms the target into a beast, robbing him [or] her [of] mind and shape. [sic]

It lets you do other things, such as turning their flesh into one of the 5 elements. Rebooting their existence as something/someone completely different with a totally new set of memories (and history, and everyone else gets appropriate memories as well). Pressing 'Delete' on the Loom of Fate, erasing the target from reality permanently.

So, this is how a Sidereal can punch you right in the Fate so hard that you turn into a Duck. Given the other things they can do with this Charm (i.e. completely rewriting your history, personality, appearance, etc), turning you into a Duck is...honestly not that bad.